# What is Iused in df -kg on UNIX?

Tags: disk-usage, aix

What is *Iused* column when running `df -kg` command on AIX server?

```
@:/logs #df -kg
Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4           1.00      0.61   39%     6103     4% /
/dev/hd2           3.00      0.56   82%    53834    28% /usr
```

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-speakingunix14/

Comment: @Ketan please expand that a little and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iused means Inodes space used. Each file in Unix-like systems has an associated data structure called Inode which stores the information about the file (sometimes called file metadata). In the output of the `df` command the `Iused` column indicated the space used by the Inodes of the files and the `%Iused` column indicates how much percentage of the total allocated Inodes space has been used so far.

One implication is that you have a realistic limits on how many files you can have on the filesystem regardless of the space.

Comment: Ahh Thank you. That last point might explain my `ksh: 0403-029 There is not enough memory available now.` error.

Comment: Does not seem likely, and the ksh error is not related to disk space at all. If you have an issue starting a shell then your initial question should also reflect that.